# RevolutionPlot3D of 4 piecewise functions around X-axis crashing mathematica

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 8.0.4 or earlier, persisting through 13.2 or later**

---

I'm trying to rotate 4 piecewise functions around the X-axis using `RevolutionPlot3D`.
The 4 functions I have are:

```
bottom[x_] := Piecewise[{{{2 + x - x^2/6}, 0 <= x < 3}}, Indeterminate]
side[x_] := Piecewise[{{7/2, 3 <= x < 15}}, Indeterminate]
top[x_] := Piecewise[{{{37/2 - x}, 15 <= x < 17}}, Indeterminate]
neck[x_] := Piecewise[{{3/2, 17 <= x <= 20}}, Indeterminate]
```

If I try to rotate all of these around the X-axis using `RevolutionPlot3D`, I get errors:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{{bottom[x]}, {side[x]}, {top[x]}, {neck[x]}}, {x, 0, 20},
                 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0}]
```

This gives me

> `Dot::rect: Nonrectangular tensor encountered.`

errors.

This has worked previously with other functions. I tried only the straight lines one for debugging; that is, `side` and `neck`:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[{{side[x]}, {neck[x]}}, {x, 0, 20}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0}]
```

But this actually crashes the *Mathematica* kernel. Any ideas how I get *Mathematica* to show a revolution plot around the X-axis of these 4 functions?

Comment: What version does this occur on?

Comment: @rcollyer I see the issue in 8.0.4

Comment: Why not merge your four functions as a single `Piecewise[]` object: `Piecewise[{{2 + x - x^2/6, 0 <= x < 3}, {7/2, 3 <= x < 15}, {37/2 - x, 15 <= x < 17}, {3/2, 17 <= x <= 20}}, Indeterminate]`?

Comment: That actually worked! The reason I didn't do that to begin with was that I was working with each function separately.

Comment: @PlatoManiac I also see it on 8.0.1.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard as you still use v7, do you see it there, also?

Comment: @rcollyer, note that the definitions of `bottom[]` and `top[]` give a list as a result, as opposed to a scalar. I can see why `Dot[]` might rightly complain...

Comment: @J.M. likely. But, I was more interested in the crash, then the rest of the problem.

Comment: @J.M., I see, that's definitely the problem then. I used Solve to get the coefficient, and then did
`a*x^2+b*x+c /. result` - that `result` should've been `result[[1]]`.

Comment: The second solution [works alright for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/W9qw8.png). Version 8.0.4 Home Edition :-) under Windows 7 Home Premium.

Comment: I filed the crash as a bug to be looked at. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I merge your four components into a single `Piecewise[]` object, things work out:

```
RevolutionPlot3D[
 Piecewise[{{2 + x - x^2/6, 0 <= x < 3},
            {7/2, 3 <= x < 15},
            {37/2 - x, 15 <= x < 17},
            {3/2, 17 <= x <= 20}}], {x, 0, 20},
           AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}, Mesh -> None, RevolutionAxis -> {1, 0, 0}]
```

[image: bottle with gaps]

though there are unsightly gaps in your bottle, which can be rectified by adding `Exclusions -> None` to the options:

[image: bottle without gaps]